# Testing if a number is a square

Tags: number-theory, fewest-operations, golf-cpu

Write a [*GOLF*](https://github.com/orlp/golf-cpu) assembly program that given a 64-bit unsigned integer in register `n` puts a non-zero value into register `s` if `n` is a square, otherwise `0` into `s`.

**Your *GOLF* binary (after assembling) must fit in 4096 bytes.**

---

Your program will be scored using the following Python3 program (which must be put inside the *GOLF* directory):

```
import random, sys, assemble, golf, decimal

def is_square(n):
    nd = decimal.Decimal(n)
    with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.prec = n.bit_length() + 1
        i = int(nd.sqrt())
        return i*i == n

with open(sys.argv[1]) as in_file:
    binary, debug = assemble.assemble(in_file)

score = 0
random.seed(0)
for i in range(1000):
    cpu = golf.GolfCPU(binary)

    if random.randrange(16) == 0: n = random.randrange(2**32)**2
    else:                         n = random.randrange(2**64)

    cpu.regs["n"] = n
    cpu.run()
    if bool(cpu.regs["s"]) != is_square(n):
        raise RuntimeError("Incorrect result for: {}".format(n))
    score += cpu.cycle_count
    print("Score so far ({}/1000): {}".format(i+1, score))

print("Score: ", score)
```

Make sure to update *GOLF* to the latest version with `git pull`. Run the score program using `python3 score.py your_source.golf`.

It uses a static seed to generate a set of numbers of which roughly 1/16 is square. Optimization towards this set of numbers is against the spirit of the question, I may change the seed at any point. Your program must work for any non-negative 64-bit input number, not just these.

#### Lowest score wins.

---

Because *GOLF* is very new I'll include some pointers here. You should read [the  *GOLF* specification with all instructions and cycle costs](https://github.com/orlp/golf-cpu/blob/master/specification.md). In the Github repository example programs can be found.

For manual testing, compile your program to a binary by running `python3 assemble.py your_source.golf`. Then run your program using `python3 golf.py -p s your_source.bin n=42`, this should start the program with `n` set to 42, and prints register `s` and the cycle count after exiting. See all the values of the register contents at program exit with the `-d` flag - use `--help` to see all flags.

Comment: I unrolled a 32-iteration loop to save ~64 operations per test. That's probably outside the spirit of the challenge. Maybe this would work better as speed divided by codesize?

Comment: @Sparr Loop unrolling is allowed, as long as your binary fits in 4096 bytes. Do you feel this limit is too high? I'm willing to lower it.

Comment: @Sparr Your binary right now is 1.3k, but I think that 32-iteration loop unrolling is a bit much. How does a binary limit of 1024 bytes sound?

Comment: Warning to all contestants! Update your _GOLF_ interpreter with `git pull`. I found a bug in the leftshift operand where it didn't properly wrap.

Comment: I'm not sure. 1024 would only require me to loop once; I'd still save ~62 ops per test by the unrolling.

I suspect someone might also put that much space to good use as a lookup table. I've seen some algorithms that want 2-8k of lookup tables for 32 bit square roots.

Comment: all the existing solutions, including mine before unrolling, fit in much much less space than that. How big is yours?

Comment: Is there a way to get access to `math` (in particular, `math.sqrt`) to programmatically generate a lookup table in the data section?  Right now I have a string of `3k` octal escapes pasted in my file...

Comment: @2012rcampion No, but you can use `x ** 0.5` to do square roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Score: 22120 (3414 bytes)

My solution uses a 3kB lookup table to seed a Newton's method solver that runs for zero to three iterations depending on the result's size.

```
    lookup_table = bytes(int((16*n)**0.5) for n in range(2**10, 2**12))

    # use orlp's mod-64 trick
    and b, n, 0b111111
    shl v, 0xc840c04048404040, b
    le q, v, 0
    jz not_square, q
    jz is_square, n
    
    # x will be a shifted copy of n used to index the lookup table.
    # We want it shifted (by a multiple of two) so that the two most 
    # significant bits are not both zero and no overflow occurs.
    # The size of n in bit *pairs* (minus 8) is stored in b.
    mov b, 24
    mov x, n 
    and c, x, 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
    jnz skip32, c
    shl x, x, 32
    sub b, b, 16
skip32:
    and c, x, 0xFFFF000000000000
    jnz skip16, c
    shl x, x, 16
    sub b, b, 8
skip16:
    and c, x, 0xFF00000000000000
    jnz skip8, c
    shl x, x, 8
    sub b, b, 4
skip8:
    and c, x, 0xF000000000000000
    jnz skip4, c
    shl x, x, 4
    sub b, b, 2
skip4:
    and c, x, 0xC000000000000000
    jnz skip2, c
    shl x, x, 2
    sub b, b, 1
skip2:

    # now we shift x so it's only 12 bits long (the size of our lookup table)
    shr x, x, 52
    
    # and we store the lookup table value in x
    add x, x, data(lookup_table)
    sub x, x, 2**10
    lbu x, x
    
    # now we shift x back to the proper size
    shl x, x, b
    
    # x is now an intial estimate for Newton's method.
    # Since our lookup table is 12 bits, x has at least 6 bits of accuracy
    # So if b <= -2, we're done; else do an iteration of newton
    leq c, b, -2
    jnz end_newton, c
    divu q, r, n, x
    add x, x, q
    shr x, x, 1
    
    # We now have 12 bits of accuracy; compare b <= 4
    leq c, b, 4
    jnz end_newton, c
    divu q, r, n, x
    add x, x, q
    shr x, x, 1
    
    # 24 bits, b <= 16
    leq c, b, 16
    jnz end_newton, c
    divu q, r, n, x
    add x, x, q
    shr x, x, 1
    
    # 48 bits, we're done!
    
end_newton:

    # x is the (integer) square root of n: test x*x == n
    mulu x, h, x, x
    cmp s, n, x
    halt 0
    
is_square:
    mov s, 1
    
not_square:
    halt 0
```

Answer (score 10):

## Score: 27462

About time I'd compete in a *GOLF* challenge :D

```
    # First we look at the last 6 bits of the number. These bits must be
    # one of the following:
    #
    #     0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11,
    #     0x19, 0x21, 0x24, 0x29, 0x31, 0x39
    #
    # That's 12/64, or a ~80% reduction in composites!
    #
    # Conveniently, a 64 bit number can hold 2**6 binary values. So we can
    # use a single integer as a lookup table, by shifting. After shifting
    # we check if the top bit is set by doing a signed comparison to 0.

    and b, n, 0b111111
    shl v, 0xc840c04048404040, b
    le q, v, 0
    jz no, q
    jz yes, n

    # Hacker's Delight algorithm - Newton-Raphson.
    mov c, 1
    sub x, n, 1
    geu q, x, 2**32-1
    jz skip32, q
    add c, c, 16
    shr x, x, 32
skip32:
    geu q, x, 2**16-1
    jz skip16, q
    add c, c, 8
    shr x, x, 16
skip16:
    geu q, x, 2**8-1
    jz skip8, q
    add c, c, 4
    shr x, x, 8
skip8:
    geu q, x, 2**4-1
    jz skip4, q
    add c, c, 2
    shr x, x, 4
skip4:
    geu q, x, 2**2-1
    add c, c, q

    shl g, 1, c
    shr t, n, c
    add t, t, g
    shr h, t, 1

    leu q, h, g
    jz newton_loop_done, q
newton_loop:
    mov g, h
    divu t, r, n, g
    add t, t, g
    shr h, t, 1
    leu q, h, g
    jnz newton_loop, q
newton_loop_done:
    
    mulu u, h, g, g
    cmp s, u, n 
    halt 0
yes:
    mov s, 1
no:
    halt 0
```

Comment: If I steal your lookup idea then my score drops from 161558 to 47289. Your algorithm still wins.

Comment: Have you tried unrolling the newton loop? How many iterations does it need, for the worst case?

Comment: @Sparr Yes, it's not faster to unroll because there's high variance in number of iterations.

Comment: does it ever complete in zero or one iterations? what's the max?

Comment: The lookup table idea was also in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686659/4339987.

Answer (score 5):

### Score: 161558 <s>227038</s> <s>259038</s> <s>260038</s> <s>263068</s>

I took the fastest integer square root algorithm I could find and return whether its remainder is zero.

```
# based on http://www.cc.utah.edu/~nahaj/factoring/isqrt.c.html
# converted to GOLF assembly for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49356/testing-if-a-number-is-a-square

# unrolled for speed, original source commented out at bottom
start:
    or u, t, 1 << 62
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope62, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 62
    nope62:

    or u, t, 1 << 60
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope60, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 60
    nope60:

    or u, t, 1 << 58
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope58, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 58
    nope58:

    or u, t, 1 << 56
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope56, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 56
    nope56:

    or u, t, 1 << 54
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope54, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 54
    nope54:

    or u, t, 1 << 52
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope52, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 52
    nope52:

    or u, t, 1 << 50
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope50, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 50
    nope50:

    or u, t, 1 << 48
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope48, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 48
    nope48:

    or u, t, 1 << 46
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope46, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 46
    nope46:

    or u, t, 1 << 44
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope44, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 44
    nope44:

    or u, t, 1 << 42
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope42, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 42
    nope42:

    or u, t, 1 << 40
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope40, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 40
    nope40:

    or u, t, 1 << 38
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope38, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 38
    nope38:

    or u, t, 1 << 36
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope36, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 36
    nope36:

    or u, t, 1 << 34
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope34, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 34
    nope34:

    or u, t, 1 << 32
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope32, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 32
    nope32:

    or u, t, 1 << 30
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope30, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 30
    nope30:

    or u, t, 1 << 28
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope28, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 28
    nope28:

    or u, t, 1 << 26
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope26, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 26
    nope26:

    or u, t, 1 << 24
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope24, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 24
    nope24:

    or u, t, 1 << 22
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope22, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 22
    nope22:

    or u, t, 1 << 20
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope20, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 20
    nope20:

    or u, t, 1 << 18
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope18, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 18
    nope18:

    or u, t, 1 << 16
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope16, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 16
    nope16:

    or u, t, 1 << 14
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope14, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 14
    nope14:

    or u, t, 1 << 12
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope12, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 12
    nope12:

    or u, t, 1 << 10
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope10, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 10
    nope10:

    or u, t, 1 << 8
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope8, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 8
    nope8:

    or u, t, 1 << 6
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope6, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 6
    nope6:

    or u, t, 1 << 4
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope4, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 4
    nope4:

    or u, t, 1 << 2
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope2, v
    sub n, n, u
    or t, t, 1 << 2
    nope2:

    or u, t, 1 << 0
    shr t, t, 1
    gequ v, n, u
    jz nope0, v
    sub n, n, u
    nope0:

end:
    not s, n        # return !remainder
    halt 0


# before unrolling...
#
# start:
#     mov b, 1 << 62  # squaredbit = 01000000...
# loop:               # do {
#     or u, b, t      #   u = squaredbit | root
#     shr t, t, 1     #   root >>= 1
#     gequ v, n, u    #   if remainder >= u:
#     jz nope, v
#     sub n, n, u     #       remainder = remainder - u
#     or t, t, b      #       root = root | squaredbit
# nope:
#     shr b, b, 2     #   squaredbit >>= 2
#     jnz loop, b      # } while (squaredbit > 0)
# end:
#     not s, n        # return !remainder
#     halt 0
```

EDIT 1: removed squaring test, return !remainder directly, save 3 ops per test

EDIT 2: use n as the remainder directly, save 1 op per test

EDIT 3: simplified the loop condition, save 32 ops per test

EDIT 4: unrolled the loop, save about 65 ops per test

Comment: You can use full Python expressions in instructions, so you can write `0x4000000000000000` as `1 << 62` :)

Answer (score 3):

## Score: 344493

Does a simple binary search within the interval `[1, 4294967296)` to approximate `sqrt(n)`, then checks if `n` is a perfect square.

```
mov b, 4294967296
mov c, -1

lesser:
    add a, c, 1

start:
    leu k, a, b
    jz end, k

    add c, a, b
    shr c, c, 1

    mulu d, e, c, c

    leu e, d, n
    jnz lesser, e
    mov b, c
    jmp start

end:
    mulu d, e, b, b
    cmp s, d, n

    halt 0
```

Comment: Nice starting answer! Do you have any feedback on programming in _GOLF_ assembly, the tools I made for _GOLF_, or the challenge? This type of challenge is very new, and I'm eager to hear feedback :)

Comment: Your answer is bugged for n = 0 sadly, 0 is 0 squared :)

Comment: @orlp fixed for n = 0. Also, I'd suggest adding an instruction to print a register's value mid-execution, which could make debugging _GOLF_ programs easier.

Comment: I'm not going to add such an instruction (that would mean challenges have to add extra rules about disallowed debugging instructions), instead I have interactive debugging planned, with breakpoints and viewing all register contents.

Comment: you could maybe speed this up by weighting your binary search to land somewhere other than the midpoint. the geometric mean of the two values perhaps?